# Навигация с помощью слайдера ui - Slider на Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Пишу тему для *Wordpress*, необходимо прикрутить слайдер для навигации, чтобы листать с помощью него страницы с постами.

После редиректа на искомую страницу позиция слайдера сбрасывается в ноль, а не остается на текущем месте.

Каким образом можно это обойти?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#slider").slider({
        step:1,
        min:1,
        value:1,
        max:<?php echo wp_count_posts()->publish;?>,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost/kit/wp-content/themes/kitchenwall/index.php&page='
                    +ui.value,
                    type:'GET',
                    data: "&page="+ui.value+"&move=1",
                    success: function(html) {
                    window.location = 'http://localhost/kit/?paged'+ui.value;
                        jQuery("#slider").slider({value:jQuery(this).ui.value});
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать текущее значение слайдера на следующую страницу. У вас два способа:

1. Через адресную строку. В вашем случае вы можете просто прочитать URL и выделить из него ui.value. Что-то вроде `var value-vziatij-iz-URL = (document.location.href.substring(27,document.location.href.length)`, где 27 - это длина фразы `http://localhost/kit/?paged`.
2. Через cookies. Только зачем?

После того, как ui.value вы передали, нужно установить в него слайдер. Просто в своем коде поменяйте настройки с `value:1,` на `value:value-vziatij-iz-URL,`, чтобы слайдер при запуске стоял на нужной странице.

Comment: Все же я бы делал через cookies. Хотя и первый вариант вполне подойдет.